# Combine backgrounds with Parrllax Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Parllax scrolling website, I have set a div that is called "bg" with 8000px height and 960px width, all page info is that size aswell, I have a body background ofcourse, when I set body background it works trough out the all page nicely, the things is I want to combine them, when I set "bg" background, it breaks the body background, I want the body background to be displayed and "bg" ontop of him without breaking him. possiable?

Code example:

```
<div class="container">
      <div id="bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    font-family:  Comic sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height:normal;
    direction: rtl;
    background: lightblue url('../images/notinuse/clouds.png') top center repeat-y;
    z-index:101;
}
#bg {
    background: blue;
    width: 960px;
    height: 8000px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
}
```

When I add background to bg it breaks the clouds when they hit bg zoom, I understand why it is happening, dont know how to make it flow.
thanks ahead.

Edit >

Here's a screenshoot, just for clear example, made it strong blue [Dropbox Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n29i5h9aawgdqz9/Screenshot%202014-02-07%2011.03.15.png).
as you guys can see, the clouds doesn't continue to the bg, I want them to be visale in the bg background.

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks the body background"? It disappears or what?

Comment: you see the line of the other background, I will a screenshot

Comment: and if you set background-color: transparent, isn't it just what you want?

Comment: Yeah! thats it, simple and true, thanks!

Comment: ok, i'll put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#bg {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```